# PHP How do I read this Object Array

Tags: php, arrays

When I do a print_r on a php variable I get this.
This is for a web application i'm working on.

```
AMC Object
(
 [Player] => AMC_Player Object
    (
        [sourceObj:AMC_Player:private] => AMC Object
 *RECURSION*
        [videoList:AMC_Player:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => 33599
                [1] => 27922
                [3] => 33640
                [4] => 27919
                [5] => 33142
                [6] => 32343
                [7] => 33143
                [8] => 31437
                [9] => 27021
                [10] => 28157
                [11] => 29719
                [12] => 28142
                [13] => 18482
                [15] => 33794
                [16] => 33079
                [17] => 33799
                [18] => 28154
                [19] => 33104
                [20] => 28010
                [21] => 28398
            )

        [videoId:AMC_Player:private] => 
        [artistId:AMC_Player:private] => 
        [userId:AMC_Player:private] => 
        [userName:AMC_Player:private] => 
        [is_songpitches:AMC_Player:private] => 
    )

)
```

I'm attemping to get the values out of the videoList private variable.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: It's a private variable, you can't directly access it, you need a getter for that. (I'm assuming you're using php5?)

Comment: Does `AMC_Player` class has any getters ?

Comment: You would need to check the class itself for getters and look for getters or check the class documentation if any is available.

Comment: I'll need to check it out.  I'm sure it has getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `get` function in the `Player` class

```
class Player{
    ...

    function getVideoList()
    {
        return $this->videoList;
    }
}
```

And also a `get` function in the `AMC` class

```
function getPlayVidList()
{
     return $this->AMC_Player->getVideoList();
}
```

`$myVidList = $AMC->getPlayVidList();`

Comment: If you didn't define these classes, maybe the getter functions are already there. GL

Comment: You've got the right idea.  Trying to incorporate.  The entire AMC class object gets created like this.

$GLOBALS['AMC'] = AMC::getInstance();

does it change anything?

Comment: the print_r of the variable above comes from GLOBALS['AMC']

Comment: @user719316 That doesn't change anything. It is just getting the instance of the class and storing it as a global. I don't know of a way to echo the methods of an object, but if there are any manuals for the library you're using I would take a look at those, or go into the source code itself if you can.